# Digitizing roads from a scanned map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, global-mapper

I have a scanned map in which roads are shown in red color, the RGB value being R>250, G=0 and B=0.

Is there a way to auto digitize the roads by specifying RGB criterion or snap criterion?

My scanned map only has the option of RGB composite or stretched under display options

Comment: In which data format (vector, raster) do you want your result? Have you considered some editing in Photoshop or similar, before importing it?

Comment: I have georef it in global mapper and exported to geotiff. I want result of digitization in vector form.

Comment: arcgis has arcscan (converts scanned images into vector-based features) source needs to be a black and white bitmap. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000w00000001000000

Answer (score 1):

You could perform a supervised classification using the Image Classification toolbar: [ESRI Image Classification](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Image_Classification_toolbar/00nv00000008000000/). Basically, you gather Training Samples of all the different features in the image...in this case you would probably just want to make the number of classes equal to the number of different colours that appear in the map.

Then, you will end up with a raster that has unique values for each of the different colours in your map. From there you would do an [Extract by Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000029000000) so that you create a new raster with only the roads features.  Finish up by running the [Raster to Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000008000000) or [Raster to Polyline](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Raster_to_Polyline/001200000009000000/) tool depending on which type of feature you want to end up with.

You may have some difficulty with the Image Classification if you are not familiar with Remote Sensing techniques, but it should be easy enough to understand with a little bit of reading.  The fact that you would be classifying a road map as opposed to some sort of imagery will make the process much simpler.